# Sphinx getting slow after continuously adding and removing items

Tags: search, sphinx

I have Sphinx search function with about 5m items. New items are added and removed continuously. Thereby Sphinx is getting slow after a while.

When i TRUNCATE RTINDEX the sphinx database and put every item back in sphinx again, than sphinx is fast again but after a while sphinx is getting slow again.

I don't want to truncate every day because it takes about an hour and a half to add the products to sphinx again.

Does someone know how to optimize sphinx to fix this problem? Maybe something with caching?

Some extra info:
Virtual memory  1021.73 MB used, 1021.99 MB total 
Real memory 10.42 GB used, 31.39 GB total

Answer (score 0):

Real-time indexes stores on disk in chunks. After a while there are many chunks, which impact performance. So, you need to optimize you index by executing OPTIMIZE INDEX command: http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#sphinxql-optimize-index